# DATE in Bootstrap issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am using Twitter Bootstrap framework for my school project and I using `<input type="date">` and it work very well in Chrome (showing some button that can displaying calendar view) but on the other browser it just like a plain text input only... any idea why?

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle or link to your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to W3Schools `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome, Safari and Opera. Reference [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: so is there any type that i can use so all websites can have same functionality like date?

Comment: For the picking part of it you could use jQuery UIs [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).